# what is the Best Approach to restrict source URL for API hitting?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, jwt

I am using laravel and AngularJS for development.
I have different portals and login page but login function is same to login all users at back end.
I want to check source URL before hitting to login function if URL is hitting from right portal to right user then it should proceed to application further other wise not.

Comment: You need to use either api/service registration or authentication methods

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna check the url then you can use **$location** provided by angular to see the url before sending the request.